# Using multiple instruments to construct bounds

Tags: causality, instrumental-variables, bounds

Suppose I have three candidate instruments $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3$ for the same endogenous variable $T$. I have no clear preference for which one the exclusion restriction is actually valid.

Can I combine the information from all three instruments to construct bounds? Suppose, I run three 2SLS regressions

$$ Y = \alpha_i + \beta_i T + u_i$$

$$ T = \gamma_i + \eta_i Z_i + e_i$$

and compute the bound as $[\min(\beta_i),\max(\beta_i)]$. Of course, getting a confidence interval on this object will be complicated as usual for bounds, but would it be valid to use this interval as a conservative bound for the true effect? If one of the three instruments is valid, then the point estimate should be within that bound, not so?

Comment: Could you define what *bound* is in your context?

Comment: I was thinking about it analogous to bounds by Manski for treatment effects
https://public.econ.duke.edu/~vjh3/e232d/readings/BOUNDS.pdf
I agree that the usage might be misleading though?

Comment: Even with one valid instrument and valid confidence intervals for that point estimate, you could always still be in one of the $\alpha$% of the cases where the confidence interval does not cover the true value. But beyond this, if the bound for your three IVs suitably widened the standard confidence interval, your chance of covering the true value would not get lower, so in principle yes, but I agree that constructing it will not be straightforward.

Comment: For different instruments $Z_i$, the 2SLS estimate $\beta_i$ [targets a different quantity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/185072), hence the direct comparison or $[\min(\beta_i),\max(\beta_i)]$ is meaningless.